# does git information in zsh prompt slows down the usage experience?

Tags: git, zsh, prompt

I am trying to set git information in the `RPROMPT` of my zsh configuration.

```
# precmd hook
function precmd {
  vcs_info 'prompt'

  if [ -z "$vcs_info_msg_0_" ]; then
    RPROMPT=''
  else
    RPROMPT=$POWERLINE_COLOR_FG_WHITE$'\u2b82'"%f$POWERLINE_COLOR_BG_WHITE $POWERLINE_COLOR_FG_GRAY"$'$(git_prompt_info)'""$'$(git_prompt_ahead)'" $POWERLINE_COLOR_FG_GRAY"$'\u2b82'"%f%k$POWERLINE_COLOR_BG_GRAY$POWERLINE_COLOR_FG_WHITE "$'$(git_prompt_short_sha) '"%f%k"
  fi;
}
```

This works well for me, but whenever I am in a git repository, the prompt becomes pretty laggy and non-responsible. It is unclear why is it the case when I see a lot of people online use git prompts in their zsh configuration. Am I doing something wrong?

[Here](https://gist.github.com/4588599) is the whole PROMPT.

Answer (score 0):

Depending how big the git repository is and how many different commands are run by the `vcs_info` plugin to generate your prompt data, fetching the info for display in your prompt can be very slow. I don't use `oh-my-zsh` or the `vcs_info` plugin in my shell prompt and fetching git info uses about a second for fetching the current branch, staged changes, and dirty changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your prompt is slow because you check the git repository status in the `precmd` hook.

You could make the prompt much faster by updating the git information only when it has changed, i.e. when you change directory (`chpwd` hook) or when you run the `git` command.

While this is not an easy task, there is zsh plugin, [zsh-git-prompt](https://github.com/olivierverdier/zsh-git-prompt), that works pretty well. Note that it requires Python.